# How should Slim be used to combine multiple REST requests?

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have a page which makes several requests using the same HTTP method to an API and displays the results.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.api.com/staff");
$staff=curl_exec( $ch );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.api.com/departments/accounting");
$departments=curl_exec( $ch );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.api.com/roles");
$roles=curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close($ch);

echo $twig->render('offices.html', ['staff'=>$staff,'departments'=>$departments,'roles'=>$roles]);
```

The API is located at https://rest.api.com, and is under my control.  The three endpoints sometimes need to be individually accessed so must remain.

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get('/users', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson(getUsers(),200);
});
$app->get('/departments/{subdept}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson(getDepartments($args['subdept']),200);
});
$app->get('/roles', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson(getRoles(),200);
});
// other endpoints...

$app->run();
```

How should the three requests be combined into a single request?  I don't wish to do something like the following as it is inflexible and requires additional documentation for each combination endpoint.

```
$app->get('/users_and_departments_and_roles', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withJson([
        'users'=>getUsers(),
        'departments'=>getDepartments($args['subdept']),
        'roles'=>getRoles()
        ],200);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you'r looking for here. You want to combine them, but at the end of your question you say you don't want to combine the requests into a single endpoint. What do you have in mind instead?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter  Wanted the combination to be more generic where each endpoint would somehow be sent together.  Ideally, it would be a standard slim method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe *combining requests* is not the best description for what you are trying to achieve, because I don't think we actually can *combine* HTTP requests. This could be easier if you wanted to use `POST` method but, to achieve this using `GET` method what you want is probably a route pattern which can be used to return multiple combination of `user`, `role` and `department` based on what caller asks for.

Assuming only numeric values are acceptable for `subdept` for the sake of simplicity, here is an example to express my general idea about the solution:

```
$app->get('/api/combine/user:{users_required:true|false}/role:{roles_require:true|false}/department:{subdept:[0-9]+|false}', function ($req, $res, $args) {

    return $res->withJson([
        'users'=> $args['users_required'] == 'true' ? getUsers() : [],
        'departments'=> $args['subdept'] == 'false' ? [] :  getDepartments($args['subdept']),
        'roles'=> $args['roles_required'] == 'true' ? getRoles() : []
        ],200);

});
```

This route will always return a result including `users`, `roles` and `departments` keys but these keys might include empty arrays as values if caller does not want any of them, and that's up to caller, but caller **must always specify if he does not want any of these keys or not** and **the order of route parameters are always the same**. For example one can access `https://rest.api.com/user:false/role:true/department:100` to get a result ignoring users (*/user:false*), a list of roles (*/role:true*) and departments for `subdept=100` (*/deptartment:100*).

A more complex pattern might help you but the general idea is to define a route pattern which can determine *what combination of available individual endpoints user wants* and return the result based on that.

Comment: Sorry about the bad description, but you guessed exactly wat I meant to say.  Let me attempt to apply.  Thanks